# How to prove these differential rules $d(AXB) = BAd(X)$ and $d(AX^TB) = A^TB^TdX$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

How can we prove the following differential rules from the basic rules:

1) $d(AXB) = BAd(X)$

2) $d(AX^TB) = A^TB^TdX$

I can write $d(AXB) = AdXB$, but how can I swap the ordering. The same issue is there with 2) as well.

$d(AX^TB) = Ad(X^T)B = A(d(X))^TB$

Any hints?

Comment: You _cannot_ prove these rules because they are not true.

Comment: @greg I found it in these notes: https://wiki.inf.ed.ac.uk/twiki/pub/CSTR/ListenSemester1_2006_7/slide.pdf. Refer slide 14. I am thinking whether it is $d(tr(AXB))$.

Comment: $D = dX$ is also a matrix. Thus, $ A D B = B A D $ is in geneneral not true.

Comment: In order to see that these rules are nonsensical, consider the case of rectangular matrices, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A &\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n},\quad
dX  \in{\mathbb R}^{n\times p},\quad
B  \in{\mathbb R}^{p\times q} \cr
}$$
The product $(A\,dX\,B)$ exists, but $(BA\,dX)$ is dimensionally impossible.